# How to escape dollar sign in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a code generator. From a map, I need to generate the same code. But some of the string values contains the escaped `$` . How to reproduce the slash before the dollar sign`\$100` ?

```
  final bar = {"bar": "\$100"}; // can have many nested and arrays of literals
  final barStr = jsonEncode(bar);

  print("""
  final foo = $barStr;
  """);
```

This doesn't work because the generated code is invalid.

`final foo = {"bar":"$100"};`

Comment: Not sure if this would work `final foo = ${barStr.replaceAll("\$", "\\\$")};` consider the edge cases

Comment: It'd be more readable to do `barStr.replaceAll(r"$", r"\$")`.  As for other edge cases, `jsonEncode` should handle other things for you (although not necessarily in ways you might want; for example, it won't escape most non-ASCII characters if you care about that).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [toEscaped()](https://pub.dev/documentation/strings/latest/strings/StringEx/toEscaped.html) from the [strings](https://pub.dev/packages/strings) package.